# KnockoutJS Two Way Binding in a foreach Loop

Tags: knockout.js, foreach

In KnockoutJS, two way binding is not working for inputs in a foreach loop. Modifying the text input does not modify the span value. This only seems to be an issue when using a foreach loop.

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: users">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: firstName"></span></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: firstName" type="text"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: lastName"></span></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: lastName" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script src="js/libs/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
function User(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

function UserListViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.users = ko.observableArray([
        new User("Joe", "Schmoe"),
        new User("James", "Ronald")
    ]);
}
ko.applyBindings(new UserListViewModel());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your `User` properties `observable`:

```
function User(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);
}
```

> **observables** are special JavaScript objects that can notify subscribers about changes, and can automatically detect dependencies.